# Operator as and ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin, classcastexception

Can I get `ClassCastException` when program is running using operator `as`, at the same time program should be compiled correctly. Maybe there is some trick with types.

For example with simple type inheritance

```
((Animal) -> Unit) --> ((Cat) -> Unit)
```

Answer (score 5):

Both `(Animal) -> Unit` and `(Cat) -> Unit` types are represented by the same class `Function1<P1, R>`. Casting one to another will never result in a `ClassCastException` since they are the same at runtime.

Comment: sorry, i mean a little another problem. Actually, i wanted to get compiling but when it is running to get ClassCastException

Comment: that's what I meant. It is not possible to get `ClassCastException` at runtime with those